2001 Jeep Grand Cherokee wheel bounce
I replaced all my shocks on my 2001 Jeep Grand Cherokee and the front two tires are still bouncing around when I hit a little bump on the road what else could it be ????

I can't see my front tires when I am driving. Please explain in more detail how you know the tires are bouncing after a bump. Feel? Sound? Steering wheel jiggle? Or are you actually driving with your head out the window so you can see the tires bounce?

I can feel it and the sound and steering wheel juggles and it only happen when the car hit a little bump

The first thing to check is the steering damper (aka steering stabilizer). Try temporarily disconnecting one end of it and force the piston in and out. It should offer resistance to movement just like a shock absorber. If the piston moves easily, it is worn out and should be replaced.
You should also check all suspension and steering components for wear, such as tie rod ends, ball joints, steering box or rack depending on your vehicle. There are videos that show how to check things, so search online, for example "video how to check tie rod ends".
If you have a specific question about a specific component, you can post a new question on this site.
